# Why can std::string which has only 32 bytes contains a string literal which has 62 bytes?

Tags: c++, string, string-literals

The book I am reading gives a **warning**:

**std::string type and character string literal are not the same type and that may cause confusion.**

However the book then does not have any accompanying examples.

**Can someone give any examples to show in what scenarios they are different?**

I have also done some investigation. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string str("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    std::cout << sizeof(str) << std::endl; //1
    std::cout << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl; //2
    std::cout << sizeof("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") << std::endl; //3
    std::cout << sizeof(L"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") << std::endl; //4
    return 0;
}
```

The output result is as follows:

```
32
32
62
248
```

I can understand the results.

But there's one thing I don't get.

**Why can std::string which has only 32 bytes contains a string literal which has 62 bytes?**

Comment: The size of a container object is not the same as the contained data. Basically a `std::string` contains a pointer to heap allocated data for the string itself, plus some meta-data like the current length. Use `str.length()` or `str.size()` to get the length of the contained string (not including terminator).

Comment: In that case `std::string` contains a pointer to the data. Not the data. That's how all resizable containers have to work.

Comment: In one word: [Indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection).